# Pi to make its own wlan AP if not connected to Home Router

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I want to have the Pi create its own Access Point for other devices to connect to,
but only when the Pi is out of range from a decent connection to a 'base / home' router?

I want to be able to have the Pi at home, and connect,
but when I'm out and about, and have the Pi on a mobile connection, I want it to create the Access Point, or Wifi Hotspot.

Comment: Take a look [ħere](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100195).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common need. There are lots of solutions out there, and lots of tutorials (that I find to be dated and inaccurate the older they are).

The solution I have been using with success is one of the Auto Hotspot scripts from [Raspberry Connect](https://www.raspberryconnect.com/projects/157-raspberry-pi-auto-wifi-hotspot-switch-internet).  Look at the different hotspot articles on that page.

Alternative options that I have not tried but came across in my search include those below; the -turnkey one seems to be well documented.

- [raspberry-wifi-conf](https://github.com/sabhiram/raspberry-wifi-conf)
- [raspberry-pi-turnkey](https://github.com/schollz/raspberry-pi-turnkey)
- [kupiki-hotspot-script](https://github.com/pihomeserver/Kupiki-Hotspot-Script)

Comment: I think you are on the right track and this is describing and walking through in detail the script and configs needed to achieve this. I courageously tried to do this while I was connected wirelessly in home network to change it, but unfortunately midway thru the setup my ssh drops connection. Ideally I should be setting this up thru ethernet. Just don't have immediate access to router this early in the day. Will try again later with Eth and report back. Thanks Chris

Comment: Got it working. Excellent tutorial using many different nuances of the topic. Thanks for sharing this, Chris.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solutions above with some success but nothing as good as I wanted. I found ComitUp as being another method of doing this. It was a lot easier.

https://davesteele.github.io/comitup/ (Thanks to Dave!)

> Comitup is a software package that provides a service to establish Wifi networking on a headless computer (that is, one with no video, keyboard, or mouse).
>
> The Comitup Image is a microSD disk image for the Raspberry Pi 3, providing an operating system with the comitup service included. The Comitup Image is an extension of standard Raspbian OS...