# Connect Raspberry Pi to Wifi using mobile app

Tags: raspbian, python, wifi, wifi-direct

I have programmed Raspberry pi to execute program which primarily works using Internet at the boot up. But it works as long as Pi is in my wifi range. Now suppose, my friend wants to use that pi in his home, but since the pi is not connected to his home wifi, it won't work. He will have to either use VNC or putty using laptop or connect screen and keyboard to Pi to connect Pi to his home wifi.

I want that any of friend could connect the pi to his home wifi, using a simple mobile app, which shows wifi in the range of Pi and we could connect Pi to any of those networks using that app. Just like Alexa does.

Comment: Looks like Alexa uses a bluetooth connection with a phone and then a phone app (and the programming on the Alexa) to configure the Alexa WiFi.  You'd have to copy this mechanism to get what you want: You'll have to write a 'simple' mobile app and add the programming to communicate with the App to your RPi.

Comment: Many IoT devices have a hotspot/AP mode that can be used to connect to them to do configuration; this is viable with the Pi.

Comment: Not sure if this is what your asking but check out [dataplicity](https://www.dataplicity.com)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pi to make its own wlan AP if not connected to Home Router](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83661/pi-to-make-its-own-wlan-ap-if-not-connected-to-home-router)